# Calculate correctly the ext2 used blocks by the file system

Tags: resize2fs, ext2

What I'm trying achieve is, a safe shrinking of an ext2 file system and make sure I can cut/shrink the physical partition underneath to a safe minimum (without cutting file system blocks). I have checked many HowTo-s, but still want to ask if I'm missing something, when determining the actual ext2 usage as reported by dumpe2fs. Here is my test case:

```
root@buster:/tmp# dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/del.img bs=1M count=1000
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB, 1000 MiB) copied, 0.429782 s, 2.4 GB/s

root@buster:/tmp# losetup -f --show /tmp/del.img 
/dev/loop0

root@buster:/tmp# mkfs.ext2 /dev/loop0
mke2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Discarding device blocks: done                            
Creating filesystem with 256000 4k blocks and 64000 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 217a401a-a001-46e8-8ca2-9602e927e2aa
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

root@buster:/tmp# mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/EXT2/

root@buster:/tmp# dumpe2fs /dev/loop0 | grep -E '(Block count|Block size)'
dumpe2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Block count:              256000
Block size:               4096
```

As I see it, the filesystem uses 1048576000 bytes (256000*4096)

```
root@buster:/tmp# cp -pr /opt/Scripts/ /mnt/EXT2/

root@buster:/tmp# umount /mnt/EXT2 

root@buster:/tmp# e2fsck -f /dev/loop0
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/loop0: 457/64000 files (6.6% non-contiguous), 67098/256000 blocks

root@buster:/tmp# resize2fs -M /dev/loop0
resize2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/loop0 to 63894 (4k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/loop0 is now 63894 (4k) blocks long.

root@buster:/tmp# dumpe2fs /dev/loop0 | grep -E '(Block count|Block size)'
dumpe2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Block count:              63894
Block size:               4096
```

After shrinking, the filesystem seems to be using 261709824 bytes (63894*4096)
May I assume than in 100% of the cases, I can safely cut/shrink the underlying physical partition to these 261709824 bytes as well? Could it be that some filesystem blocks are still physically located after these 261709824 bytes?

Comment: I prefer to use gparted for that - less chance you can f something up. It's so easy to miscalculate and lose data otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately, this should be bash automated. No chance for GUI applications.

Comment: `parted` is a console application which offers automation.

Comment: I'm afraid in its latest versions parted, doesn't support filesystem resizing and you have to use resize2fs, which I'm already using:

             ** `resizepart partition end
                     Change the end position of partition.  Note that this does not modify any filesystem present in the partition.`**

As the topic suggest, what bothers me is exactly, once the filesystem is shrinked, how do I make sure I resize the partition to a safe minimum, without affecting blocks of the filesystem.